# UIImageView does not fade in, but out

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiimageview, fade

I created an imageView with which I would like to display an error. I use animations to fade the image in / out. This is the code I use for the animation:

```
    imageView.hidden = NO;
    imageView.alpha = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
        imageView.alpha = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        imageView.hidden = NO;
    }];


    imageView.alpha = 1;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 delay:4.5 options:0 animations:^{
        imageView.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        imageView.hidden = YES;
    }];
```

So my image does fade out as it should but it does not fade in, why ever. Do you have an idea?

Comment: You need to set the `hidden` property to no before the first animation, after you've set `alpha` to 0.

Comment: @BrianShamblen Oh yes I did that, I just did not put it in the comment, let me edit this.

Comment: @BrianShamblen Nope, still not working

Comment: Remove the `imageView.alpha = 1` between the two animations.

Comment: @BrianShamblen No changes there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I normally put the additional animations within the completion block of the first animation. I tested this and it works for me. If this doesn't work, check to make sure your `imageView` property is connected properly in your layout file.

```
imageView.hidden = NO;
imageView.alpha = 0.0f;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
    imageView.alpha = 1.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f delay:4.5f options:0 animations:^{
        imageView.alpha = 0.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        imageView.hidden = YES;
    }];
}];
```

Comment: Great! Thanks :)
But could you maybe explain why it does not work my way?

Comment: Also, if I have animations without a delay your solution will not work. So do you have another one?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's going on under the hood, but according to Apple's 'View Programming Guide', they recommend placing any additional animations within the completion block. Check the section titled 'Linking Multiple Animations Together' here https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html

Comment: I've had to hack it in the past by using 0.01f as the duration. It, in effect, is a zero length but it still works.